# Is it safe to have an internal ClusterIp backend service using HTTP behind an Ngynx Ingress controller accessible via HTTPS?

Tags: security, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a Service configured to be accessible via HTTP.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myservice
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

And an Ngynx Ingress configured to make that internal service accessible from a specific secure `subdomain.domain`

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myservice-ingress
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/myservice-ingress
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myservice.mydomain.com
      secretName: myservice-ingress-secret-tls
  rules:
    - host: myservice.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: myservice
              servicePort: 80
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - {}
```

So when I reach `https://myservice.mydomain.com` I can access to my service through HTTPS.
Is it safe enough or should I configure my service and pods to communicate only through `HTTPS`?

Comment: Could you please paste logs from NGINX Ingress controller? And how did you installed the ingress: via helm or Kubernetes?

Comment: can you tell me why do you need the logs ? I installed the ingress with kubectl, but nginx  and certmanager has been installed with helm

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behaviour since you've set `TLS` in your Ingress.

> Note that by default the controller **redirects** (308) to **HTTPS** if TLS **is enabled** for that ingress. If you want to disable this behavior globally, you can use ssl-redirect: "false" in the NGINX [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#ssl-redirect).

To configure this feature for specific ingress resources, you can use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` annotation in the particular resource.

About your question: "Is it safe enough.." - it's opinion based question, so I can answer to use better `HTTPS`, rather than `HTTP`, but it's just my opinion. You can always find the difference between `HTTP` and `HTTPS`

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor well I will wait for other answers to have a better idea, because about security I need more than one opinion ^^ . Technicaly my services using HTTP dont have any external termination, only a internal IP so they cannot be reached from the outside, only trought the Nginx controller that use HTTPS, so in my opinion it's safe, but if the traffic could be intercepted inside the cluster it's another problem, if it is possible (and everything is possible even if it's hard ...). I also have other services that use a self signed certificate and are reachable trought 443.